# How to sort a nested dictionary by letter?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, character

I have a problem. I have a `dict`. This contains abbreviations. This dict should be sorted according to the `shortForm`. First all short forms with `A, B, ..., Z`.
I have tried it with `sorted`, but this does not work as desired. Now my question is how can I sort my dict by letters so that I get the desired output (see below)?

**Code**

```py
final_output = {
    "abbreviation_knmi": {
        "symbol": "knmi",
        "shortform": "KNMI",
        "longform": "Koninklijk Nederlands Meteorologisch Instituut"
    },
    "abbreviation_fbi": {
        "symbol": "fbi",
        "shortform": "FBI",
        "longform": "Federal Bureau of Investigation"
    },
    "abbreviation_eg": {
        "symbol": "eg",
        "shortform": "e.g.",
        "longform": "For example"
    }
}
sorted_list = sorted(final_output.keys(), key=lambda x: (final_output[x]['shortform']))
print(sorted_list)

[OUT] ['abbreviation_knmi', 'abbreviation_fbi', 'abbreviation_eg']
```

**Desired Output Dict**

```json
{
    "abbreviation_eg": {
        "symbol": "eg",
        "shortform": "e.g.",
        "longform": "For example"
    }
    "abbreviation_fbi": {
        "symbol": "fbi",
        "shortform": "FBI",
        "longform": "Federal Bureau of Investigation"
    },   
    "abbreviation_knmi": {
        "symbol": "knmi",
        "shortform": "KNMI",
        "longform": "Koninklijk Nederlands Meteorologisch Instituut"
    },
}
```

Comment: `dict(sorted(final_output.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['shortform']))`

Comment: @OlvinRoght thank you for your comment. This only returns my list, which is not sorted. The `sorted` is not done.

Comment: Well, it's not, but you want case-insensitive sort, so `lambda x: x[1]['shortform'].lower()`

Comment: A side note - I really don't see the benefit in creating the nested structure you work with and especially the way you create keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems its already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

```
final_output = {
    "abbreviation_knmi": {
        "symbol": "knmi",
        "shortform": "KNMI",
        "longform": "Koninklijk Nederlands Meteorologisch Instituut"
    },
    "abbreviation_fbi": {
        "symbol": "fbi",
        "shortform": "FBI",
        "longform": "Federal Bureau of Investigation"
    },
    "abbreviation_eg": {
        "symbol": "eg",
        "shortform": "e.g.",
        "longform": "For example"
    }
}

sorted_dict = dict(sorted(final_output.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['shortform']))
print(sorted_dict)
```

Output:

```
{   'abbreviation_eg': {   'longform': 'For example',
                           'shortform': 'e.g.',
                           'symbol': 'eg'},
    'abbreviation_fbi': {   'longform': 'Federal Bureau of Investigation',
                            'shortform': 'FBI',
                            'symbol': 'fbi'},
    'abbreviation_knmi': {   'longform': 'Koninklijk Nederlands Meteorologisch '
                                         'Instituut',
                             'shortform': 'KNMI',
                             'symbol': 'knmi'}}
```

Comment: add `key=lambda x: x[1]['shortform'].lower()` and it will be a correct answer.

Comment: Missed that though it was just about sorting base dictionary my bad !! Thanks @OlvinRoght for pointing it out